# How to write .htaccess that preserves $_POST and removes file extension consistently?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

This morning, I was trying to remove file extensions from a website I am working on.  While I am not familiar with .htaccess files, I am trying to learn them and their regex online.  The first one that I tried failed to preserve $_POST values, and therefore broke the website.  I found this longer block of .htaccess code on here and tried using it, and it fixes the post issue well.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

However, I have found that while it drops extensions well, when I go to certain files or back from them, my files have their extensions back.  This appears to stop when I destroy the session.  I hope this does not seem like a trivial or repeated question, but I find it unusual that some files have their extensions hidden while others do not.  For example, I will see Site/home, then go to Site/about.php, and when I come back I will be at Site/home.php.  Is there something obvious I am missing here?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The .htaccess file works, for anyone trying to do the same thing.  My forms were going to Site/about.php, which I assumed would automatically correct to Site/about.  I went through my code and removed all file extensions from forms, hrefs were fine.  This fixed it, so far no bugs!  Thank you all who considered this question.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php

Comment: Are you just suggesting that I add that line below RewriteEngine On?  If so, I tried that, and it did not fix the problem.  Thank you for your answer, but will you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
```

`RewriteRule ^about?$ Site/about.php`

OR

`RewriteRule ^Site/about?$ Site/about.php`